# Weak wifi signal on Lenovo g series

Tags: wireless, lenovo, signal

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo laptop and the wifi signal reception changed completely.

I had Windows installed on it first and it had no problem connecting to my home network from my bedroom (to a router in another room). Now it only finds the network if I step outside the room.

An other computer in my room and my smartphone find the network and connect without any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978457
or better http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wchimaoe9KE
From what I have seen I would go first with the Youtube video.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.